# Is Watchkit app required to show remote notifications of the app on Apple watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios-app-extension, watchos-2

I am creating an application that should show remote notifications on Apple watch.
I have set all the required icons for Apple watch on my AppIcons assets.
My watchkit app will only exist to show the received notifications and be able to read them.

Unfortunately I don't have an Apple watch to know the answer.
So my question is the following:
Is it necessary to create a Watch kit app for this purpose? or the received remote notifications on my device will also be shown on the watch without needing to create a WatchKit app?

In addition, and in case that the notifications are not shown on the watch without creating the watchkit app, how should I remove it from the list of apps shown on the watch since no functionality other than showing notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, if the user owns an Apple Watch, all the notification he receives on his iPhone are also displayed on the Watch where he can read them, with no need to add icons or even to create a WatchKit app.

I have an Apple Watch and I receive all Snapchat and Facebook notifications, even if these apps are not available on that platform.

However quick notification actions (such as Reply) are not shown unless you have an app.